# git: key does not contain a section

Tags: git

I am using Git version 1.8.4.2.

When I press <kbd>tab</kbd> to auto complete any command, it prints the error below and it also completes the command.

> error: key does not contain a section: --get-regex

Can anyone please help to avoid this error?

Comment: which operative system are you working on?

Comment: it is SUSE linux version.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **.gitconfig** in your home directory and see if it has **'--get-regex'** in it somewhere it should not be.

Also check **.git/config** in the repo you are working in for the same string.

PS : A colleague was having the same issue and his ***~/.gitconfig*** had extra stuff causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when my .gitconfig file in my user directory all of a sudden was mal-formed. Things were not properly structured in there. So I had to open it and fix it.