# Git Error - key does not contain a section

Tags: git, github

I recently transferred a git repository to a new organization. I ran the following:

`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/organizationname/therepo.git`

I am successfully pulling/pushing from the new location. But now getting the following errors every time I run a git command:

```
error: key does not contain a section: repositoryformatversion
error: key does not contain a section: filemode
error: key does not contain a section: bare
error: key does not contain a section: logallrefupdates
error: key does not contain a section: ignorecase
error: key does not contain a section: precomposeunicode
```

I initially thought it had to do with my config file however those fields are present. The first lines of My `/.git/config` file looks like this:

```
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
ignorecase = true
precomposeunicode = true
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624705/git-key-does-not-contain-a-section) it suggests to check for `--get-regex` but I do not see any reference to that in my config or `.gitconfig` files. It looks like I have 2 git config files:

`/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig`

and:

`/Users/chmd/.gitconfig`

I tried adding those keys to `/Users/chmd/.gitconfig` file with no such luck. What step am I missing to clear out these errors? Based on previous answer and research it seems to be my config, but I'm including those fields in my gitconfig?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Indeed, the problem is in `.git/config`. You probably edited it and you removed the name of the section by mistake.

The values in Git config file are grouped in sections. The name of each section is placed between square brackets on a separate line.

The values you posted (from the beginning of your `.git/config`) should stay in the `core` section. Make your `.git/config` file look like:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ...
```

Comment: Ah hah! That was it. I wasn't aware a remote change would affect that. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: I didn't have an issue with this until after. I don't really know what happened....

Comment: @kawnah are you sure you didn't edit `.git/config` by hand? It's highly improbable the file ended up this way after a correct usage of Git. Or, maybe, you are using a GUI client that doesn't use `git config` to handle the config file and it ruined yours.

Comment: @axiac no I would not edit that. I use atom as my text editor. Maybe it did something?

Comment: @axiac can you post the all content of .git/config my config file is similar as you posted

Answer (score 14):

> paste the following code to terminal it will open global config file in VI text editor

```
git config --global --edit
```

press i to write in VI text editor and remove all the text and paste the following

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
ignorecase = true
precomposeunicode = true
```

to save in VI press ESC and :wq and press enter

Answer (score 9):

This is not your case, but responding here for other people with the same issue as me. I had this error message:

```
error: key does not contain a section: name
error: key does not contain a section: email
```

It turns out I had messed up something in my  `~/.gitconfig` file.

To fix it, I looked at [this example](https://gist.github.com/pksunkara/988716) and realized the first section of that file should look like this (fake example data):

```
[user]
    name = Bart S
    email = bart.s@example.com
    username = barts
```

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

[Git configuration](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) is organized in sections.

It's:

- [`core.repositoryformatversion`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corerepositoryFormatVersion)
- [`core.filemode`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corefileMode)
- [`color.ui`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-colorui)
- ...

Your `.git/config` should look like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

## git config [section] solutions

> fix git [section] warnings

1. global config

```sh
$ vim ~/.gitconfig

[user]
  email = xgqfrms@xgqfrms.xyz
  name = xgqfrms
```

```sh
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
```

2. project local config

```sh
$ vim .git/config

[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true

[user]
  name = xgqfrms
  email = xgqfrms@ufo.com
```

```sh
$ cat .git/config
```

### demos

```
error: key does not contain a section: email
error: key does not contain a section: name
```

> before

[image]

> after

[image]

Answer (score 1):

key does not contain a section *global*

If you are getting this type of error, it is because you type *global* keyword without adding the double dash(`--`) before it like this `--global`:

Wrong:

```
git config global diff.tool vscode
```

Correct:

```
git config --global diff.tool vscode
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

error: key does not contain a section: user
Was getting this error when I was doing:

```
git config --list user
```

All I had to do was do:

```
git config --list user.name
```

or

```
git config --list user.email
```